# Hom over algebras and modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebras

I'm working on the following question:

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative and unital), $f: R \rightarrow B$ be a $R$-algebra, $M$ an $R$-module and $R$ a $B$-module. Show that

$\text{Hom}_B (B \otimes_R M, N) \simeq \text{Hom}_R (M,N)$.

Now for a moment if we forget about the algebra $B$, I know that $\text{Hom}_R(R \otimes_R M, N) \simeq \text{Hom}_R (R, \text{Hom}_R (M, N))$ holds for $R$-modules. Also, I know that there is a canonical isomorphism $\text{Hom}_R (R, M) \simeq M$.

I could try to realize $B$ as a $R$ module, but I'm confused about $R$ being a $B$-module. Would that imply that I'm just realizing $R$ as a module over itself? How exactly does the subscript on $\text{Hom}$ play out in here?

Comment: It looks like this is just a type and it should say "and $N$ a $B$-module", not $R$ as a $B$-module

Comment: Looks like it is in fact a typo, since N was not specified in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is an $R$-algebra. It becomes an $R$-module if we define "$rb$" as $f(x)b$
for $r\in R$ and $b\in B$.

Likewise, a $B$-module $N$ becomes an $R$-module via $rn=f(r)n$.

Also $B\otimes_ RM$ is a $B$ module via $b\sum b_i\otimes m_i
=\sum(bb_i)\otimes m_i$.

So here we are claiming that the $B$-module homomorphisms from
$B\otimes_R M$ to $N$ (where $N$ is considered as a $B$-module)
correspond to the $R$-module homomorphisms from $M$ to $N$
(where $N$ is considered as an $R$-module).

Roughly speaking if $\phi:M\to N$ is an $R$-module homomorphism
then the corresponding $B$-module map takes $\sum b_i\otimes m_i$
to $\sum b_i\phi(m_i)$.

In the language of category theory, the functor $M\mapsto B\otimes_RM$
is a left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $B$-mod to $R$-mod.

Comment: That makes sense. So, morally if knowing that B being a R-algebra it has a R-module structure, I can "ignore" the algebra structure and work only with the module structure?